# Using maven to create junit xml reports of jar

Tags: java, maven, junit, jar

I have inherited a codebase whereby we have a maven project of component tests that use junit as the framework that runs the tests.

Everything runs OK, but the problem is that these tests must be compiled into a jar-with-dependencies so that they can be run on a standalone computer with very limited outwards connectivity (e.g does not have access to maven central).

I have managed to create a runnable jar with dependencies which I can run using junit.jar and the command line like so:

> java -cp jar-with-dependencies.jar:junit.jar junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.testsuite.AllTests

This works but the problem is that I also need to output the junit results into XML, like maven's surefire plugin does.

My question is, can I run this jar-with-dependencies using maven such that it creates the junit xml reports?

I can successfully run the tests using exec-maven-plugin which essentially runs the previously stated command

Comment: I'm afraid the generation of xml reports is a feature of surefire, not junit. That would be quite difficult to reproduce without having the maven runtime. One thing the could work is to take maven binaries + the whole maven repository and with a bit of configuration, you would be able to successfully run maven from your limited computer.

Comment: @spi just to clarify. I can use maven, it is installed on the machine, but it will run in offline mode, so I just have to bundle all the dependencies needed to run the tests.

Comment: then that should work, just be sure to deliver with your jar a copy of your maven repository, containing all the required dependencies and plugin. Then maven won't try to connect to internet if it already have everything it needs. There is also the maven flag ```-o``` which turn it in offline mode: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-offline-option

Comment: Yeah, it looks like its possible, problem is I'm not sure how to do it. Looks like my best bet is to unpack the jar using maven on the "blocked" machine, and then using surefire to run the junit from the .class files. Though I can't get it to work

Comment: then, how about just running maven on the source as usual? What I don't get is if you have maven, what prevents you to launch ```mvn clean test``` in your limited computer (obviously after updating your maven local repository with everything needed)?

Comment: I'm totally with you. The requirement is to have a zip file that someone can just take, unzip somewhere and "run" an executable that sits within it. So, it should be a complete standalone package that can be run. Packaging the source code is great, problem is that the end user does not want to touch the m2 repo at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161120/discussion-between-spi-and-user475680).